# The best way to always sync device contacts with my server

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contacts

I have an activity which shows all device contacts. This activity has a bad performance because it always get the contacts on the `onCreate()` method. I really don't know how to solve this problem.

**Note:** I need to know a new contact has added to the device or a contact has registered to my service always to have updated contacts list (the contacts which have registered to my service)

Can you please help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly post code you are using to load the contacts.

It is fine to load the contacts from the `onCreate()` but make sure you are using a Loader. Doing a synchronous query from `onCreate()` or any other life-cycle method, or anywhere else from UI thread will affect the UI and can cause ANR.

For listening to changes use :

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contentobserver);
```